# Tomcat creating new thread for same session

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, sessionid, stripes

I have a webapp that uses Stripes and the Apache Shiro library for security.

On my local Windows Tomcat 6.0.33 installation everything works fine.  However, when I run the app on Tomcat 6.0.16 on Linux at my host DailyRazor, I can see that periodically Tomcat is spawning a new thread for the same user/session, and so the user is losing their credentials and being asked to login again.

I also noticed this on my dev box when running under Jetty.

I don't think it's an inactivity timeout issue as the hits I am giving the webapp are sequential, is there something in the Tomcat config that may be different, apart from the different minor versions?

Alternatively, is there an easy way to debug the session info (as it's not appearing in my urls)?

Comment: Does it start a new thread in the middle of a request handling? Or does it start a new thread to handle a new request. If the latter, that's to be expected. Do you store credentials in a ThreadLocal and hope it will always use the same thread for the session?

Comment: You can dump the session ID by logging it normally--but you say you already know it's the same session, how do you know that? A user's session may exist across any number of threads.

Comment: @JBNizet I am logging when a request is received and this can be different for different requests from the same browser window.  I believe Shiro is storing the credentials in a ThreadLocal as there is a static call to get the current subject, am I not guaranteed that a thread will be analaguous to a session ID?....phrasing it like this, I feel like I already know the answer

Comment: @DaveNewton Is that definitely the case?....I assumed that a thread was private to a session, is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @JamesB Each new request will be handled by an arbitrary thread; sessions are not related to threads. What kind of documentation do you want? The TC docs state "each incoming request requires a thread for the duration of the request". Just because something stores data in a `ThreadLocal` doesn't mean that information isn't stored at/near the beginning of each request.

Comment: @DaveNewton Point taken, I guess I'm looking for an idiot's guide to Tomcat, I know roughly how to put a webapp together, but how this interacts with Tomcat itself I'm not so clear on (as this question is evidently showing!)

Comment: @JamesB Log the session info in your action bean. Are you crossing HTTP/HTTPS boundaries? How are you determining the user lost their creds, via a framework class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6010/discussion-between-james-b-and-dave-newton)

Answer (score 3):

Just to make it clearer than if it was in a comment: Each HTTP request will be handled by an arbitrary thread. Tomcat (and other app servers) use a pool of threads, pick a thread from the pool, execute the request, and give back the thread to the pool.

The HTTP session is completely orthogonal to the threading: several requests from the same session may be handled by different threads. A thread executes requests from several sessions. There are typically much more parallel sessions than threads in the pool. And finally, you may very well have two threads executing two requests for the same session. That implies that the objects stored in the session should be thread-safe, or that a synchronization mechanisme should be used to access non-thread-safe objects stored in the session.

Moreover, multiple frames or tabs of a given browser share the same HTTP session. You'll have a different session if you start a different browser (Chrome in addition to Firefox, for example), or if you use a browser on another machine.

Comment: I'd figured that from what you said in your comments.  It makes perfect sense if I stand back from the problem and look at how someone would implement something like Tomcat.  Thanks for the answer, I think I'm going to turn my application inside out, and use the Shiro servlet up front for security, and then figure out how to embed the stripes framework inside that, instead of calling Shiro from a stripes interceptor.